# How to align an object relative to another object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, alignment

Here's my two objects:

[image]

I'd like to quickly place the selected (small) circle in the center of the gray one. So its aligned vertically and horizontally in the middle.

How can I do it? What's the best procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Select both objects
- Click the reference object once, the selection mark gets thicker
- Align

[image: align]

Comment: This is super useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

2 ways to do this:

- Drag the green circle anywhere inside the grain circle. hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to open the 'Align' panel then click the horizontal and vertical centering icons, after making sure the 'Align to Selection' is selected
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (outline mode), then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (smart guides), grab the center of the green circle and drag it until it touches the center of the gray circle. The mouse pointer should then change to let you know the centers are snapping.